# Similarity of matrices with specific characteristic polynomial

Tags: linear-algebra

We have the matrix of anti-clockwise rotation by $90$ degrees as an example of a matrix that does not have any eigenvalue when considered over the field of real numbers. Now, its characteristic as well as minimal polynomial is $x^2+1$. I am trying to characterise all real matrices with the above characteristic polynomial. My guess is that they are all similar but I am not being able to prove it. Since the Jordan canonical form does not exist, I don’t know how to proceed further. If we are to generalise further, when are two matrices having same and equal characteristic and minimal polynomials similar?

Comment: All this is dealt with by the Rational Canonical Form Theorem.

Comment: In addition to rational canonical form (AKA Frobenius normal form), you can also use the [real Jordan form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jordan_normal_form#Real_matrices)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a direct proof that all such matrices are similar.

Let $A$ be a $2 \times 2$ matrix such that $A^2 + I = 0$. Let $x$ be any non-zero vector. We note that $\{x,Ax\}$ forms a linearly independent set; otherwise, $x$ would be an eigenvector of $A$. Thus, (the ordered set) $\mathcal B = \{x,Ax\}$ is a basis of $\Bbb R^2$. In order to find the matrix of $A$ relative to this basis, we find that
$$
Ax = 0x + 1Ax,\\
A(Ax) = A^2x = (-I)x = -1x + 0Ax.
$$
Thus, we find that the matrix of $A$ relative to this basis is given by
$$
[A]_{\mathcal B} = \pmatrix{0&-1\\
1&0},
$$
which is the matrix corresponding to the anticlockwise rotation by $90^\circ$.

Thus, every $2 \times 2$ matrix satisfying $A^2 + I = 0$ is similar to the anticlockwise $90^\circ$ rotation matrix, so that all such matrices are similar to each other.

---

As an alternative characterization, note that a matrix $A$ will satisfy $A^2 + I = 0$ if and only if it can be written in the form

$$
A = \pmatrix{y&x\\-(y^2 + 1)/x&-y}
$$
with $x,y \in \Bbb R$ and $x \neq 0$.